# Automapper: null collections handling

Tags: automapper

This post is more like a RFC. I'm collecting opinions before creating the Issue on Github to be sure that it's reasonable.

The subject is

> When mapping a collection property, if the source value is null
>   AutoMapper will map the destination field to an empty collection
>   rather than setting the destination value to null. This aligns with
>   the behavior of Entity Framework and Framework Design Guidelines that
>   believe C# references, arrays, lists, collections, dictionaries and
>   IEnumerables should NEVER be null, ever.
>   https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/automapper/latest/automapper.pdf

I find it quite unexpected. I don't think, that forcing a developer to follow the behavior of Framework Design Guidelines is the area of concern of Automapper. It can be optionally enabled, but it shouldn't be a default setting, because null value and empty collection are different things.

What do you think?

Comment: This is not going to happen. Backward compatibility.

Comment: I use EF a lot with AutoMapper... so I'm glad this is the default behavior